# How to move the block along its width (only css)

Tags: html, css

I want to move the block to the left along its length.
How I can do this?
[image]

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. Please elaborate.

Comment: You might want to add a bit more code and explanation of what you are attempting to do. What you have is not enough to help you with a specific problem

Comment: What block? Set up a quick jsfiddle, dude. Help us help you.

Comment: I add a picture, I hope you understand what I want.

Comment: CSS rule. `margin-left: -300px;` Without code, it's extreamly hard to help.

Comment: @MaximPro this still doesn't give us much to go on. Are you wanting to slide (animate) the text? I'd suggest you create a fiddle using jsfiddle with what you have tried so people can help you.

Comment: @blackandorangecat content might be various, I don't know how much I must margin

Comment: @MaximPro `Float: left` will make the element stay on the left side, though it will likely mess up other things.

Comment: below, dude correctly understand me, but used js

Answer (score 0):

simple example, **pure css** :

```css
.mytext {
  border: 8px black solid;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  left: 300px;
  width: inherit;
  height: 60px;
  transition: 2s;
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
  -moz-transition: 2s;
  position: absolute;
}

.mytext:hover {
  left: 0;
}


.mytext2 {
 margin-top: 100px;
  border: 8px black solid;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  transition: 2s;
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
  -moz-transition: 2s;
  position: absolute;
}


@keyframes slideToLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.mytext2 {  
  /* This section calls the slideInFromLeft animation we defined above */
  animation: 2s ease-out 0s 1 slideToLeft;
}
```

```html
<div class="mytext">text</div>
<div class="mytext2">text2</div>
```

Comment: You correctly understood what I want, but I do not need js

Comment: @MaximPro , If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as 
[Correct answe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!

Comment: not bad, but i don't know width of block, it might be 50px or 300px or 1500px (dynamic content such as inline-block)

Comment: @MaximPro it does not matter, you can use `width: inherit;` if your block inside a container, all you need to know is left, event you don't have left, there are too many way of doing it, does it solve your problem?

Comment: Block "text" moves more than himself size - it's wrong. Him size is 83px. He must moves only on 83px or depending on the size of the content of the block.